# 401 Unauthorized error with $http and hedear param in in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

I am trying to a $http request with passing header params for login page, but its return 401 Unauthorized error. I have no idea any wrong code done.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    var params = {"Username":"test", "Password":"test"};

    $http.post('http://192.168.6.168:9090/EOZAPI/api/1.0/secure/login/', {headers: params
    }).success( function (data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(headers());
    })
    .error( function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(headers());
    });

  }]);
```

Comment: the api you are using `192.168.1.168:9090` is coded as such... if you are authorized use pass the token with the api call in authorization header

Comment: Fixed the issue with below code
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Username"] = 'test';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Password"] = 'test';

Answer (score 0):

why not just pass params? I m sure you ll need some more params if its is giving you an unauthorized error Response.

the JSON sent as parameter should be

```
 $http.post('http://192.168.6.168:9090/EOZAPI/api/1.0/secure/login/', params)
   .success( function (data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(headers());
    })
    .error( function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(headers());
    });
```

OR If you need to set some header:

```
  $http.post('http://192.168.6.168:9090/EOZAPI/api/1.0/secure/login/',
    {headers: someHeaderJson, data: params})
       .success( function (data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log(headers());
        })
        .error( function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(headers());
        });
```

PS: this is the code on angular's site. Found on this [page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

PS2: Try using POSTMAN or something to verify if the requested URL i.e. http://192.168.6.168:9090/EOZAPI/api/1.0/secure/login/ is working or not.

Comment: But its fine with jquery $.ajax
$.ajax ({
            url: "http://192.168.6.168:9090/EOZAPI/api/1.0/secure/login",
            headers: { 'EatOutz-username': 'test','EatOutz-password':'test' },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader ("username", "test");
             xhr.setRequestHeader ("password", "test");
            },
            method:"POST",
            success: function(val) { 
             console.log(val); 
             alert("success" + val);
            },

Comment: someHeaderJson means the same params?

Comment: no it would be like {token: xyz, content-type: 'application-something'}